# How to not respond to a request on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, http, flask

One defence to timing attacks is to not respond to a request at all if a call fails to pass a challenge, since that provably reveals no timing information about the comparison.

Is there a way in Google App Engine/Flask to not respond to a request?

I would think one could use e.g. `sleep(TIMEOUT)` where `TIMEOUT` is greater than the maximum time for App Engine to respond, but I am concerned about this causing a denial of service since it'll be leaving threads dangling.

Comment: From what I understand, that may also cause the scheduler to spin up new instances are your current ones have "stopped responding" or are responding slowly.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood - Yeah, badness all around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not.

The fact that its hitting a route means your web service has already 'handled' that connection and the damage has been done.

The best thing to do is `abort(404)`.

If you really want to add extra defense you need to use additional services, but there isn't anything you can do at an application level. As you said, sleeping will just keep the connection open. Your best action is to just handle it with as low overhead as possible.

Comment: Further, if you do something timing-sensitive to validate the request, since closing the TCP connection provides timing information, you should make the request block until a constant amount of time has passed. The better approach would be to use timing-resistant algorithms in the first place.

Comment: I would however ( if worried of a ddos attack ) not use a timing sensitive method. Maybe create a secondary service to provide this. Or at least make sure you have your wgi setup correctly to handle these types of requests.